# JAXB - namespace handling in XML output

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I am trying to generate an XML document similar to one i already have.

So I generated xsd for that xml using some tool (i remember with the one that ships with Visual Studio compiler), and then generated jaxb classes through Eclipse. Now I am able to marshall an XML output successfully with slight differences with respect to the Original xml document i refer. One difference is the namespace. all the namespace elements are not present in xml output.

The **original document** has the namespace structure like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<ClassPackage xmlns="http://www.example.com/in-CLASS/1.0" xmlns:name1="http://www.example.org/Schemas/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/in-CLASS/1.0 C:\schemas\in-class.xsd">
```

I have got the following header in the **marshalled output** XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<ClassPackage xmlns="http://www.example.com/in-CLASS/1.0">
```

I have the **package-info.java** class generated as follows:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.com/in-CLASS/1.0", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.test.xml;
```

Kindly help me in getting the namespace elements similar to the **original document**.

Comment: very strange for me that I dont have an answer from SO for a long time! was so confident when i posted of answers when i turn up after few hours... :(

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the name1 namespace cause it is not used in any of your subelements of ClassPackage object.

If none of the other objects belongs to those namespaces, they will not be printed.

You can declare additional namespaces in your XmlSchema annotation:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
namespace = "http://www.example.com/in-CLASS/1.0", 
xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="name1", namespaceURI="http://www.example.org/Schemas/XMLSchema"))
```

But you should checked that your generated xsd schemas were namespaced aware cause it is suspicious that the xml had additional namespaces declarations but no elements belonged to it. Since, xml schema typically is defined one for  a namespace, you should have have additional xsd document for your name1 schema which is imported in the man xsd document.

Without seeing the whole xml document it is hard to say if the namespaces are artifacts or should they be really used by some of your elements.